# Alternatives to Parse for a Social App?

Tags: ios, parse-platform, backend, mbaas

I recently delved into app development on Xcode, and decided to develop a social app. I was using Parse as my mbaaS for a while, but unfortunately they are closing down. I was wondering in your experience what is(are) the best alternatives to Parse. Im basically using looking for something 
1) easy to use 
2) Well documented 
3) Lots of tutorials 
4) Can handle lots of RPS and users.
The app I am developing is a social app, so if you have any specific recommendation for an app of that type, that would help tremendously. Also it is important to note that I have no backend development experience, so it would be a challenge to develop my own.
Thanks again

Answer (score 3):

There are several Parse alternatives out there right now:

**[AWS Mobile Hub](https://aws.amazon.com/mobile/)** - this is a direct Parse replacement that recently came out by AWS. Although this is in Beta, AWS is a well respected    platform that supports many huge companies like Netflix and Yelp

**[Firebase](https://www.firebase.com/)** - (acquired by Google) Firebase offers a great solution for    real time communication and data storage. It's perfect if what you    are doing is mainly data & realtime (chat, game, collaboration,    etc...) but it's not very flexible for other things (e.g. payment,    SMS, push notifications etc...) firebase.com

**[RapidAPI](https://www.rapidapi.com/)** - a backend platform that allows for saving data and integrating APIs. It is based on blocks so each basic action is represented by a block. You can combine blocks to create logic. It has a bit of a higher learning curve but it's probably more flexible

**[BackAnd](https://www.backand.com/)** - a platforms that allows you to create an AngularJS ready backend for your app. Its really good of you are working on AngularJS web apps and your data is stored on Amazon RDS.

Comment: I have been looking a firebase a bit, and right now thats the route I'm leaning towards. One preliminary problem I see is the lack of a built in username. It uses email instead which is not what I need. I think ill have to create my own custom authentication if I went that route which is fine, I would just prefer a built in function.

Answer (score -1):

Baasbox is a good alternative to Parse. A lot of features used in Parse are there (Push messaging etc), so migrating an app is relatively straightforward. They provide an API for Android, iOS and Javascript.

One of the main advantages it has over Parse is that it can be hosted yourself (Although there is a hosted option available, but it's not free).

http://www.baasbox.com

Out of all the available backends, we found this to be most similar to Parse.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that Parse can now be hosted yourself, with the [open source Parse Server](http://blog.parse.com/announcements/introducing-parse-server-and-the-database-migration-tool/).